# How to construct the blind factors in practice?

Tags: encryption, public-key, cryptanalysis, implementation

I'm Implementing a protocol that uses masking techniques (or blinding factors), so we can mask a value $y_0$ as $m_0=y_0 \cdot r_0$ where $y_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $r_0 \stackrel {R}\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$ (let $_p$ be a prime number) and the $m_0$ can be unmasked as $m_0\cdot r^{-1}_0=y_0$ at any time.

My Question is: what function do I need to use to get $r_0$ (or $r_i$ in general)?

Can I Use Pseudo-random generators (PRG)? Why?

Answer (score -1):

Blinding technics are well know now to defeat most attacks against SCA.
You need a random number generator (True or Pseudo) to generate unpredictable random $r_i$.
Additionnal precautions against Zero Attacks values can alo be taken. 
Try this: $m_0=y_0 \times r_0 \; + \; r_1 \times p \; mod \;(r_2 \times p)$

Comment: What is meant by _Zero Attacks_ ? Any relation to _Zero-Value Point Attacks_ ?

Comment: If I use PRG, I need to pick a seed first, then I specify the range, t get a uniformly random value. What should I do for the next $r_i$ (e.g. $r_1$) using the seed same seed?

Comment: What do you mean by SCA?

Comment: @cygnusv: SideChanelAttacks for short, but other kinds could be considered

Comment: @user13676: preferably $r_0 \; and \; r_1$ should be in the same magnitude of the initial or the blinded modulus. By the practice, it's enought to chose a small random value for $r_2$.

Comment: @fgrieu: Yes. Depending of the evolution during the computation, some values containing a large range of zero bits could leak. You know how some faults attacks could force the computation registers to such values.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI Ok, so you mean "*Blinding technics are well know now to defeat most SCA*"?

Comment: I have added one more line to the question.